# Как разместить два блока так, чтобы при адаптивной верстке разместить их как на макете?

Tags: html, css

Теперь понятней, существует определенные блоки с содержимым, которое расположено через раз по разному(см. изображение ниже). Как разместить их в десктопной версии я понимаю, а как мне расположить их содержимое так, чтобы при адаптивной, они все были в одном порядке?

Как блоки выглядят в десктопной версии:
[image: десктоп версия]

Как блоки должны будут выглядеть в версии для планшетов:

[image: версия для планшетов/телефонов]

Вроде задание простое, но я почему-то уже второй раз с ним сталкиваюсь и второй раз не могу понять как сделать ПРАВИЛЬНО при адаптиве. Спасибо ВСЕМ за помощь! :)

Comment: почитайте про grid. вот хороший гайд: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Так это все таки через grid делается? Хорошо тогда, почитаю, спасибо большое :)

Answer (score 2):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sparklingman/4zp731qr/)

```css
*,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font: 18px/1 sans-serif;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 24px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
}

section div {
  align-items: center;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  section {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Page style</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section>
      <div>Стартовая страница</div>
      <div>В командировке как дома</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div>Таблица №1</div>
      <div>Страница выдачи</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div>Персонализация выбора</div>
      <div>Таблица №2</div>
    </section>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, что помогли! Подходит идеально

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что вам может подойти решение на Flex. Но вообще такие большие блоки все таки сетка и делать их лучше на Grid. Этим потом очень легко управлять!

Решение на  flex.

```css
* { 
 box-sizing: border-box;
}  

body { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
} 

.col2-flex {  
  display: flex;   
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper { 
  margin: 0 auto;  
  max-width: 1280px;
}   

.business__img { 
  display: block;  
  width: 100%; 
} 
 

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .business__info { 
      order: 1;
  }  
    
  .col2-flex {  
    display: flex;   
    flex-direction: column;
  }
    
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>CodePen Home
flex-adaptive</title>
</head>
<body>  
  <section class="business"> 
    <div class="wrapper col2-flex">  
      <div class="business__info"> 
        <h2 class="business__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2> 
          <p class="business__text">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, adipisci minima assumenda ut quia repudiandae praesentium libero ducimus perspiciatis debitis ad porro cumque ipsum quod mollitia facere, provident quis ipsa, nulla possimus eius quibusdam maiores sapiente placeat. Omnis ipsam quae dolore cum, veniam asperiores! Totam ea minima voluptas a quisquam, quaerat magnam veniam repellat odit. 
        </p> 
      </div> 
      
      <div class="business__pack"> 
        <img class="business__img" src="https://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Creative-Button-Styles.jpg" alt="btn styles">
      </div>
    </div> 
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Я как раз таки и пытался сделать через Flex, но не додумался как именно, все таки опыта еще немного не хватает. Нужно учить Grid, решение на Flex конечно тоже хорошее, но как Вы уже сказали на Grid будет лучше. Еще раз спасибо! :)